# The DOM element created by CSS3DObject cannot be obscured by the GL plane

Tags: three.js, frontend, webgl

I found that it seems to be solved by setting the `blending` attribute of `material`, but it still cannot be solved after trying.

[Incorrect occlusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lKie.png)

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import {GLTFLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
import {
   CSS3DRenderer,
   CSS3DObject
} from "three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"
import dat from "dat.gui"

function initThree() {
   const scene = new THREE.Scene();
   const scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

   const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      50,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      10000
   );

   camera.position.set(0, 0, 2500);
   scene.add(camera);

   const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true,
   });
   renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   document.querySelector('#webgl').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

   const labelRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer()
   labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
   labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
   document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

   scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(1000))

   const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, labelRenderer.domElement);
   controls.enableDamping = true;

   const clock = new THREE.Clock()

   window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   });

   return {
      scene,
      scene2,
      camera,
      renderer,
      labelRenderer,
      controls,
      clock,
   }
}

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()

const gui = new dat.GUI()

const {
   scene,
   scene2,
   camera,
   renderer,
   labelRenderer,
   controls,
   clock
} = initThree();

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight("#ffffff", 1)
scene.add(ambientLight)

const position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 900, 300);
const rotation = new THREE.Euler(0, 0, 0);

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.style.width = '1000px';
container.style.height = '1000px';
container.style.opacity = '1';
container.style.background = '#1d2e2f';
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = "http://csyedu.top"
iframe.style.width = "1000px"
iframe.style.height = "1000px"
iframe.style.padding = 10 + 'px';
iframe.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
iframe.style.opacity = '1';
container.appendChild(iframe);

const object = new CSS3DObject(container);
// copy monitor position and rotation
object.position.copy(position);
object.rotation.copy(rotation);
// Add to CSS scene
scene2.add(object);

// Create GL plane
const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
material.opacity = 0;
material.transparent = true;
// NoBlending allows the GL plane to occlude the CSS plane
material.blending = THREE.NoBlending;
// Create plane geometry
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000);
// Create the GL plane mesh
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
// Copy the position, rotation and scale of the CSS plane to the GL plane
mesh.position.copy(object.position);
mesh.rotation.copy(object.rotation);
mesh.scale.copy(object.scale);
// Add to gl scene
scene.add(mesh);

gltfLoader.load("./models/computer_setup.glb", model => {
   const texture = textureLoader.load("./models/baked_computer.jpg");
   texture.flipY = false;
   texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
   const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture,
   });
   model.scene.traverse((child) => {
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
         child.scale.set(900, 900, 900);
         child.material.map = texture;
         child.material = material;
      }
   });
   scene.add(model.scene)
})

function render() {
   const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
   controls.update();
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
   labelRenderer.render(scene2, camera)
   requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

The effect I want is that the 3D mesh can correctly occlude the CSS3DObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I runned over the same problem, I'm trying your code and works good on my project, I think you have a styling problem.

I have separated the WebGL and CSS3DRenderer on the html.

```
<body>
  <div id="css"></div>
  <div id="webgl"></div>
</body>
```

```
#css, 
#webgl
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
}
```

If I only put the #css on absolute this is the result
[image: working bad]

If I put both in absolute it works fine.
[image: working good]

I wish that'll help